# Rights of a retouched work

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing, retouching

I'm currently retouching photos for a client that is a bit skimpy on payment. 
Would watermarking my retouched version of their image be within my rights as a retoucher?

I don't want them to have the ability to use my work before I'm paid, but I'm not sure if I have the right to watermark since I don't own the original image.

What should I do?

Comment: IANAL but it would have be significantly *retouched* to be a derivative work, otherwise I wouldn't expect a client to pay for something illegal you were doing.

Comment: I was approached by this client to retouch a few provided photos for a book that she is in the process of writing. Not exactly sure how being asked to retouch photos by the owner of said photos is illegal, but I honestly don't know too much about the legal aspects of the situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copyright has "nothing" to do with the watermark. At least not in this case.

You do not have the right to commercialize the images for example. In this case, the watermark can simply be marked as "Preview" only.

But the thing that is going to protect you more effectively is a contract.

Comment: So as long as I don't claim copyright, I could theoretically watermark any line of text into the retouched image and be well within my bounds?

Comment: In my opinion, the line should be something that actually is. "preview only", "Retouching pending for approval".

Comment: Even better than a contract is a retainer applied against final invoice.

Answer (score 3):

All such rules vary by venue, I am not a lawyer, and this is not legal advice but I offer a slightly different answer to the also correct one by @Rafael:  You are asking about your "rights".  You have no rights beyond the contract you have with the photographer. Whether that contract is written or oral, vague or specific, that is the limit and the extent of your rights.  And basically you have no rights to the image at all. What implied rights and processes exist are driven by whatever understanding you had, and common practice where you are (if any).

If you really wanted to know you need a lawyer, though I would expect this is too small a job to merit one.

One way to think of the question is whether, if you fail to deliver a usable (un-marked) image, do you have a right to expect payment? Has that been discussed?  Would the most common practice be to deliver a final (un-marked) product, then get paid?  If so, then changing that practice without discussion might be considered acting in bad faith.

The way to deal with all this is, up front, with a clear contract. It does not even have to be written (again, depending on venue) to be binding, but written is much easier to prove. Specify delivery and payment and any "preview" measures.

One fairly general thing to consider: The first person to fail to follow through with the mutually agreed (or at least expected) process is going to look like the bad guy. Saying "I just did it because I expected to not be paid" would not convince most reasonable people. And I'm sure this is not big enough to go to court, but if so you always want to come with "clean hands", i.e. having fulfilled all your commitments.

And if this person has a reputation for non-payment WITH YOU, besides asking why you are doing more work, you might just call them and say "last time you took forever to pay, can we discuss delivery and payment now" and work it out. Don't surprise them, is my advice.